# How to perform a nested loop on one array in such a way that the first counter is never equal to the second

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, rake

How to loop over the same array twice like this

```
array.each do |k|
 array.each do |l|
 end
end
```

in such a way that k is never equal to l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way in my opinion would be to make it a single loop:

```
(array.product(array) - array.zip(array)).each do |(k, l)|
  ...
end
```

---

Two less elegant approaches:

```
array.each do |k|
  (array - [k]).each do |l|
    ...
  end
end
```

or

```
array.each do |k|
  array.each do |l|
    next if k == l
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I wanted to recommend the last version, that is the most readable, and it is more important in many cases than a little performance boost, after all, its time complexity is O(n*n)

Comment: Good answer, mudsie. A couple of small points. 1. As you know, you don't need the parentheses in `|(k, l)|`. Readers: they're only needed when you have something like `...each_with_object({}) {  |(k,l),h| }`, or `...each_with_index.with_object({}) { |((k,l),i),h}|`. 2. You are creating two temporary arrays, `array.product(array)` and `array.zip(array)`. You could avoid those by writing `array.product(array).reject! { |k,l| k==l }`.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the elements of the array are unique:

```
array.permutation(2) do |k,l|
end
```